# Retrieve data to dropdown list using Jquery, Ajax & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal that inputs the details of the event and I want the attendees of the event to be displayed below after selecting their names. All of the data is now inserted but I have one problem. The event is displayed using the jquery fullcalendar. But my problem is how can I retrieve the names of the attendees inside this dropdown list using jquery. Inside my database, I have a attendees table which contains the firstnames and last names of the teachers and events table which contains the event details. I am to use an associative table for this one and I have created already which contains the id of the attendee, id of the event as foreign keys and id of the group as primary key.

here is a code snippet of my function in my calendar to insert my data:

```
function modal(data) {
    //alert(data);
    // Set modal title
    $('.modal-title').html(data.title);
    // Clear buttons except Cancel
    $('.modal-footer button:not(".btn-default")').remove();
    // Set input values
    $('#title').val(data.event ? data.event.title : '');
    if (!data.event) {
      // When adding set timepicker to current time
      var now = new Date();
      var time = now.getHours() + ':' + (now.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + now.getMinutes() : now.getMinutes());
    } else {
      // When editing set timepicker to event's time
      var time = data.event.date.split(' ')[1].slice(0, -3);
      time = time.charAt(0) === '0' ? time.slice(1) : time;
    }
    $('#time').val(time);
    $('#description').val(data.event ? data.event.description : '');
    $('#venue').val(data.event ? data.event.venue : '');
    $('#color').val(data.event ? data.event.color : '#3a87ad');

    // Create Butttons
    $.each(data.buttons, function(index, button) {
        $('.modal-footer').prepend('<button type="button" id="' + button.id + '" class="btn ' + button.css + '">' + button.label + '</button>')
      })
      //Show Modal
    $('.modal').modal('show');
  }
  // Handle Click on Add Button
$('.modal').on('click', '#add-event', function(e) {
  if (validator(['title', 'description'])) {
    $.post('query/events/addEvent.php', {
      title: $('#title').val(),
      description: $('#description').val(),
      color: $('#color').val(),
      venue: $('#venue').val(),
      date: currentDate + ' ' + getTime()
    }, function(result) {
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
    });
  }
});
```

this is a sample form where I will choose the attendees of my events:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="attendees">Attendees</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="teacherDropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me what to do with this?

Comment: by the way, the calendar is already initialized and also the time and dates

Comment: I don't see PHP code.

Comment: <?php
 // Require DB Connection
 require_once('connect.php');
    // Add Event
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO event2 (title,  event2.date, description, color, venue) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
 $sth->execute(array($_POST['title'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['color'], $_POST['venue']));

Comment: @JoseRojas php code up above this comment